# SAPUI5 OPA5 How to trigger a select event

Tags: integration-testing, sapui5

Below a typical action to test if a sap.m.Select contains an item with the name xyz and then select it.

```
success: function(oSelect) {
    var oItems = oSelect.getItems();
    $.each(oItems, function(i,v) {
        if(oItems[i].getText() === "TestItemNameILikeToSelect") {
            oTestOpa5TestItem = oItems[i];
        }
    });
    if(oTestOpa5TestItem !== null) {
        oSelect.setSelectedKey(oTestOpa5TestItem.getKey());
        oTestOpa5TestItem.$().trigger("tap");
    }
},
```

When I start the test run it does correctly select the proper item from the list and sets it visibly in the browser, but it does not trigger the attached event that is behind (e.g. change="onListItemChanged").
My application works fine, but I don't find a way to create a working test for it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPA5 has an 'Action' interface and two default implementations e.g. 'EnterText' and 'Press'. The recommended usage is to define an `action` block on the `waitFor()` options like this:

```
When.waitFor({
    id: "myButton",
       actions: new Press()
    });
```

What you use is the 'old way' but it has some shortcomings:

- `success` block is not synchronized with XHR requests but `action` is.
- Sending a click/tap event to a control could require selecting some internal element. Imagine a click to nav container - there are several places you could click actually. Actions handle those details and define a standard behavior you could depend on.
- It is better to encapsulate your selection logic inside a `matchers` block and even abstract it to a custom matcher. This way your `success` block will be cleaner and you could reuse the matcher in several places in your test.

[OPA5 Actions](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8615a0b9088645ae936dbb8bbce5d01d.html)

Comment: Thanks. Short addition: it seems necessary to open the dropdown (press event), then set the key and tap the visible element.

Comment: This is one way and it would definitely work. But with OPA5 you have a better way - match the dropdown control and just call .setSelected() method to select the necessary item.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the official UI5 Demo Kit, under samples > OPA5 > Code: Simulating user interactions on UI5 controls with OPA5, You will be able to find numerous examples of OPA 5 testing regarding general user interactions. In your case for the select:

```
opaTest("Should select an item in a sap.m.Select", function(Given, When, Then) {
        When.waitFor({
            id: "mySelect",
            actions: new Press(),
            success: function(oSelect) {
                this.waitFor({
                    controlType: "sap.ui.core.Item",
                    matchers: [
                        new Ancestor(oSelect),
                        new Properties({ key: "Germany"})
                    ],
                    actions: new Press(),
                    success: function() {
                        Opa5.assert.strictEqual(oSelect.getSelectedKey(), "Germany", "Selected Germany");
                    },
                    errorMessage: "Cannot select Germany from mySelect"
                });
            },
            errorMessage: "Could not find mySelect"
        });

    });
```

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.test.Opa5/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.OpaAction/code/Opa.js